# How to set width to dropdownbutton items

Tags: flutter, dart

I have reproducible example https://dartpad.dev/db7c5955d36cf0d06f475c65b947d77d . The question is how can change long text width to desired one?
Desired:
[image]

(made screenshot when made selectedItemBuilder string longer)

Comment: Your question is unclear, what is your desired width? SS or SSSSSSS

Comment: @bluenile now long text is wrapped with width of dropdown button but I need to make it bigger in such a way that long text is not wrapped

Comment: Are you trying to fit the text?

Comment: @harundemir918 I'm trying to make items width longer than width of dropdown button

Answer (score 0):

Set

```
isExpanded: true,
```

for your **DropdownButton** widget

or Follow this link
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56736584/how-can-i-change-the-width-padding-of-a-flutter-dropdownmenuitem-in-a-dropdownbu/56767046#:~:text=You%20can%20control%20the%20width,padding%20to%20that%20Container%20widget.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56736584/how-can-i-change-the-width-padding-of-a-flutter-dropdownmenuitem-in-a-dropdownbu/56767046#:%7E:text=You%20can%20control%20the%20width,padding%20to%20that%20Container%20widget.)

Comment: I don't need to expand button width. I need to set width only for items

Comment: I have updated the answer with a link. Hope that will help you